# sql - select a row at random and update it

Tags: mysql, sql

My table isn't too gigantic, so I think the method of getting a random row like this is acceptably fast:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

However, what I really need to do is to also update that randomly found row in the same step, before any other connection gets to it. Here's my attempt which runs indefinitely long and I have to kill:

```
BEGIN;
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE jobs SET started = NOW(), id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
WHERE id = (SELECT jtemp.id FROM (SELECT * FROM jobs) as jtemp WHERE jtemp.started IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
SELECT @update_id;
COMMIT;
```

The `@update_id` thing is since I need the row I've actually chosen returned to the client for later updating.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't think the random row selection is the bottleneck here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd love to hear why this is a good idea.  Why would you want to randomly change a row?  A database should be a permanent record of what happened.  How do random changes fit?

Comment: I'm randomly choosing a row to operate on. Once chosen, I don't want another worker to start this job, thus needing to mark it started. It's really a pretty reasonable plan.

Comment: You might want something like this.  Be sure to set a timeout to unlock the row if the worker goes away without finishing.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @duffymo I don't see exactly how this would let me see the id of the row I just updated. merely using the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is fairly simple. is there a way within a transaction to get the last selected row (and also return it)?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work.

```
update yourtable
set field1 = value1
etc
where id = 
(select id
from yourtable
order by rand()
limit 1)
```

Comment: but how do I get the id of the row I just updated? this is pretty much what I did, minus the temp table. which was too slow / didn't work.